# Why does the spatial coverage of Landsat 5 deteriorate over Alaska further back in time?

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat, landsat-5, coverage

I am working in Google Earth Engine to retrieve Landsat images over Alaska. As I am doing so for each year, I realised that the coverage of Landsat 5 deteriorates the further back in time you go. Specifically, before the 2000's only Western Alaska was partly covered, see image for the year 1998.

The code I have been using is:

```
// Load the Landsat 8 surface reflectance collection
var image_96 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C02/T1_L2')
                .map(applyScaleFactors)
                .map(maskL8sr)
                .filterBounds(AK)
                .filterDate('1997-09-01', '1997-10-31')
                .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER', 50))
                .mean();

// Load the Landsat 8 surface reflectance collection
var image_97 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C02/T1_L2')
                .map(applyScaleFactors)
                .map(maskL8sr)
                .filterBounds(AK)
                .filterDate('1997-09-01', '1997-10-31')
                .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER', 50))
                .mean();

// Load the Landsat 8 surface reflectance collection
var image_98 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C02/T1_L2')
                .map(applyScaleFactors)
                .map(maskL8sr)
                .filterBounds(AK)
                .filterDate('1998-09-01', '1998-10-31')
                .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER', 50))
                .mean();
```

[image]

Why does this happen the further back in time you go, also for Landsat 4? Is it simply because of [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/296362/155292) answer?
And, is there an alternative to this with a somewhat similar spatial resolution?